# Path to static content with Embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using embedded Jetty to serve static content from the "public" folder in my project:

```
    Server server = new Server(9999);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/");

    ServletHolder staticHolder = new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet());
    staticHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "./public");
    context.addServlet(staticHolder, "/*");

    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Which works fine. However, if I change

```
    context.addServlet(staticHolder, "/*");
```

to

```
   context.addServlet(staticHolder, "/ui/*");
```

or

```
   context.addServlet(staticHolder, "/ui");
```

or anything other than "/*" I get a 404. Basically I can see my index page at http://127.0.0.1:9999/index.html, and I would like to change it to http://127.0.0.1:9999/ui/index.html.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jetty embedded file server servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/jetty-embedded-file-server-servlet)

Comment: pay attention to `pathInfoOnly` in the prior answer

Comment: That's the bit of code I needed! I don't think it's a duplicate, since my question was specifically about the path.

Answer (score 1):

As posted here:

[Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/jetty-embedded-file-server-servlet)

I needed to add:

```
staticHolder.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
```

which allowed me to modify the path and have it behave correctly:

```
context.addServlet(staticHolder, "/ui/*");
```

allowing access to static content at http://127.0.0.1:9999/ui/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Avalanche.
Also if you serving static content you should add
`staticHolder.setInitParameter("useFileMappedBuffer", "true");`
to avoid  [Locked Files on Windows](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/troubleshooting-locked-files-on-windows.html)