# Jetty resource base in a sibling project

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, multi-project

I need to configure my Jetty server so that it can serve static HTML files from one project and REST responses from a second project however I can only seem to get the REST side to work...

I have a project structure similar to:

```
+-project-core
|    +-src/main/java/jetty/JettyRunner.java
|
+-project-web
|    +-src/main/webapp/static/index.html
|
+-project-REST
     +-src/main/java/resource/RestResource.java
```

My JettyRunner sets up a Server like:

```
    // REST (JERSEY 2.0 stuff)
    WebAppContext restHandler = new WebAppContext();
    restHandler.setResourceBase("./");
    restHandler.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    restHandler.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

    ServletHolder restServlet = restHandler.addServlet(ServletContainer.class,  "/rest/*");
    restServlet.setInitOrder(0);
    restServlet.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "resource");
    restServlet.setInitParameter("useFileMappedBuffer", "false");

    // Web - note I can't use a ResourceHandler because it doesn't allow the init param I require below
    WebAppContext webHandler = new WebAppContext();
    webHandler.setResourceBase("../project-web/src/main/webapp/static");
    webHandler.setInitParameter("useFileMappedBuffer", "false");
    webHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});

    // Server
    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.addHandler(webHandler);
    handlers.addHandler(restHandler);

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(handlers);
    server.start();
```

The REST side of things seems to work fine, I can hit `localhost:8080/rest/someendpoint` which returns a `200` but when I hit `localhost:8080` I get a directory structure of `project-core` and not the index.html file I was expecting. If I hit `localhost:8080/index.html` I get a `404`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered in [Serving Static Files from Alternate Path in Embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty).

You don't want another `WebAppContext`, just add another specific `DefaultServlet` on your original `WebAppContext`.

> Note: `WebAppContext.addServlet()` does exist. [`WebAppContext`
>   extends `ServletContextHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html) as seen in the other answer.