# Embedded Jetty web app context/holders serving from two resource bases with one web.xml (spring secuity)

Tags: spring-security, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I have an existing application which is using the embedded jetty. Right now jetty has only one WebappContext and serving the files from a directory and also it has web.xml (which has spring security configuration in it)

Now I need to serve some static files using a new war.

What is the easy way to configure existing webappcontext to add a new resource base?

If I add new webappcontext how I can tell jetty to use existing web.xml and spring security?

Answer (score 0):

The serving of static files is just the role of the `DefaultServlet`

See prior answer about that ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20223103/775715

As for the existing web.xml and spring security question, the WebAppContext's are, by design, and by the nature of the servlet spec, isolated from each other.

If you want a single spring security configuration that applies for both webapps, you'll need to setup/install [CAS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html).