# Deploy Static content in jetty

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I am trying deploy the app static in jetty, but using xml config file, because i am using virtual hosts.

I create this file xml for deploy:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
  "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/mail</Set>
    <!--<Call name="setInitParameter">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.useFileMappedBuffer</Arg>
        <Arg>false</Arg>
    </Call> -->
    <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="resourceBase">/ccmail</Set>
      <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>

    <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>apps.cairunet.ad.br</Item>     
    </Array>
  </Set> 

</Configure>
```

The name for my folder app is `ccmail`. Is located in `webapps/ccmail`
I already try pass to path for:

`<Set name="resourceBase">/ccmail</Set>`

`<Set name="resourceBase">ccmail</Set>`

`<Set name="resourceBase">./ccmail</Set>`

`<Set name="resourceBase">webapps/ccmail</Set>`

`<Set name="resourceBase">/webapps/ccmail</Set>`

Anyone this paths not works for me.

Jetty launch this error:

> 2019-02-25 09:36:46.422:WARN:oejs.ServletContextHandler:main:
>   ServletContextHandler.setHandler should not be called dire ctly. Use
>   insertHandler or setSessionHandler etc. 2019-02-25
>   09:36:46.484:WARN:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:main: Can't generate
>   resourceBase as part of webapp tmp dir name:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No resourceBase or war set for
>   context 2019-02-25 09:36:46.500:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed
>   startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7d0587f1{/mail,nul
>
> l,UNAVAILABLE,apps.cairunet.ad.br} java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   resourceBase or war set for context
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:577)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:152)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:579)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77) 2019-02-25 09:36:46.578:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@27808f31{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0: 8080}
>   2019-02-25 09:36:46.594:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @2970ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: be careful with your DOCTYPE, what you have declared is from Jetty 7.x thru Jetty 8.x, and is not correct for Jetty 9.x

Don't mix ResourceHandler and WebAppContext / ServletContextHandler.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/mail</Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>apps.cairunet.ad.br</Item>     
    </Array>
  </Set> 
</Configure>
```

The most basic support is to not reference `/ccmail` in your `<Configure>`.

The fact that it exists as `${jetty.base}/webapps/ccmail/` is enough, that will deploy `/ccmail` as a static resource base for you.

BUT if you want to combine static resources with virtual hosts, then you can either use a WebAppContext with an alternate base, or a new ResourceHandler.

Example of alternate bases:
[Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty/20223103)

Example of ResourceHandler usage:
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/static-content-deployment.html

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/ccmail</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="resourceBase">/fully/qualified/path/to/my/jetty.base/webapps/ccmail</Set>
      <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>apps.cairunet.ad.br</Item>     
    </Array>
  </Set> 
</Configure>
```