# Scala Jetty webapp on Heroku 404

Tags: scala, heroku, jetty, udash

I'm testing around with a Scala web framework (Udash) and trying to run a toy-example in Heroku. I have it running without issues in local following the instructions in the Heroku docs:

```
sbt compile stage
heroku local web
```

However, once deployed, any URL I type goes to 404, even the landing page of the app. These are the objects I am using:

```scala
object Launcher extends CrossLogging {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val port = Properties.envOrElse("PORT", "5000").toInt
    val server = new ApplicationServer(port, "frontend/target/UdashStatics/WebContent")
    server.start()
    logger.info(s"Application started...")
  }
}

class ApplicationServer(val port: Int, resourceBase: String) {
  private val server = new Server(port)
  private val contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler
  private val appHolder = createAppHolder()

  contextHandler.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler)
  contextHandler.setGzipHandler(new GzipHandler)
  contextHandler.getSessionHandler.addEventListener(new org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport())
  contextHandler.addServlet(appHolder, "/*")
  server.setHandler(contextHandler)

  def start(): Unit = server.start()
  def stop(): Unit = server.stop()

  private def createAppHolder() = {
    val appHolder = new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet)
    appHolder.setAsyncSupported(true)
    appHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", resourceBase)
    appHolder
  }
}
```

Is there any Heroku configuration/characteristic that I am missing?

**EDIT**

Tried to apply the changes suggested and ended up with the following ApplicationContext:

```scala
class ApplicationServer(val port: Int, val resourceBase: String) {
  val server = new Server()
  val connector = new ServerConnector(server)
  connector.setPort(port)
  server.addConnector(connector)
  private val appHolder = createAppHolder()

  val context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS)

  context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(resourceBase))
  context.setContextPath("/")
  context.addServlet(appHolder, "/")
  server.setHandler(context)

  private def createAppHolder() = {
    val appHolder = new ServletHolder("default", classOf[DefaultServlet])
    appHolder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true")
    appHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", resourceBase)
    appHolder
  }

  def start(): Unit = server.start()
  def stop(): Unit = server.stop()
}
```

However, I still get Error 404 even on landing page after deploying to Heroku:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /. Reason:
    Not Found
```

When running the app on local I get to the landing page correctly.

Thank you!
Thanks!

Comment: Your code works, as long as I put something into the directory pointed at by `resourceBase` to obtain via the browser. (eg: I put a `hello.html` with a simple `<h1>hello world</h1>` in it and then accessed it via `http://localhost:8080/hello.html`)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to adjust that might help you.

1. `resourceBase` as a init-parameter on `DefaultServlet` is for [alternate static file serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty/20223103).
2. Use `ServletContextHandler.setBaseResource(Resource)` instead.
3. Use `Resource.newResource(String)` to create a new Resource reference.  This should be an absolute path on the filesystem, or an absolute URI reference. no relative paths or URI fragments.
4. The `DefaultServlet` must be on the `url-pattern` of `"/"`, not `"/*"` (this is a servlet spec requirement)
5. The `DefaultServlet` must be named, and must have the name `"default"` (this is a servlet spec requirement, see link on point 1 for example)
6. set the `ServletContextHandler.setContextPath("/")` to be explicit about what base context-path you want to use.

Some observations:

Your example code will only serve static content out of the `resourceBase`.

Since you have no `welcomeFiles` configured it would serve `<resourceBase>/index.html` by default (if you don't specify a specific static resource you want to access)

You have a `SessionListener` setup (`org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport`), but since there's nothing that would access a `Session`, that code is pretty much a no-op.

There's no dynamic results from a custom Servlet or Filter present in your example codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, gonna try it out once I get home and I'll let you know

Comment: Hello @Joakim! Tried out the changes you suggested without success. I used the other answer you linked as template. I am sorry as I get a bit lost with all the server stuff (: I think, however, that I applied correctly your suggestions (new applicationServer I used is here https://gist.github.com/pmbrull/64de6497d52463542cc2ca902a03ffb4) I would really appreciate further guidance on this while I keep looking for examples and docs. Tyvm!!

Comment: Can you update your question (edit it) and include how you are running the code, and what results you see, vs what results you are expecting?