# Serving static content outside the WAR with Embedded Jetty

Tags: servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a WAR (being served through Embedded Jetty) that I'd like to include static files *outside the WAR*.  My goals are:

- Serve static files from a path outside the WAR, relative to the directory the Embedded Jetty is running.  So, if I invoke the jar in `/srv/app`, I'd like to configure a URL of `http://myapp.com/static/js/my.js` to serve `/src/app/public/js/my.js`.
- Secure: No directory listings or `../` path escapes
- Not reinvent the wheel: I don't want to write a new Servlet, but rather harness existing capabilities
- Ideally (not required): Shadow the static content in the WAR, so that if I have a `/src/app/public/index.html`, that file will be served, and, if not existent, the WAR's `index.html` will be served.

Here's what I examined, and where I'm stuck:

1. DefaultServlet: Seems ideal, but, I can't find any way to have it serve files outside the WAR.  **Is there a way for the DefaultServlet to serve static content outside the WAR, with paths relative to the app's pwd?**
2. Configuring Jetty, as described in https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/static-content-deployment.html ; this would seem to be ideal, but, when copied in, didn't seem to do anything (it was a NOOP).
3. ResourceHandler: Is this the right way to do it? I wasn't able to figure out how to use this to make my goals

Answer (score 0):

> ResourceHandler: Is this the right way to do it? I wasn't able to figure out how to use this to make my goals

Don't use `ResourceHandler`, its inferior to `DefaultServlet`.

> Configuring Jetty, as described in https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/static-content-deployment.html ; this would seem to be ideal, but, when copied in, didn't seem to do anything (it was a NOOP).

This only works if you don't share the same `contextPath` as your deployed webapp.

> Is there a way for the DefaultServlet to serve static content outside the WAR, with paths relative to the app's pwd?

Yes, and this has been documented on stackoverflow in a few different ways.
Key is, you'll use extra `DefaultServlet` entries, defined with their own "Resource Base Path" (which has to be a fully qualified path entry, no relative paths), on different `url-patterns`.

See:

- [Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20223103/775715)

Comment: Can you elaborate how this should be done? I'm new to Jetty and Servlets, and would like to use your answer to guide my implementation.