# Access session from ResourceHandler in jetty

Tags: jetty

Is there a way to read session from ResourceHandler like you can do it from ServletContextHandler?
Something like this:
                `request.getSession(true).setAttribute("test", test)`

Answer (score 1):

The `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` is only present on contexts that belong to a  `javax.servlet.ServletContext`.

So no, you cannot access it from a `ResourceHandler`.

Why do you need to do this for a static resource, and cannot just use the more complete static file serving feature-set of the `DefaultServlet` found within a `ServletContextHandler`?

And yes, you can have it serve static resources from alternate locations.

[Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty)

Comment: because we use extension of ResourceHandler for access handling. And ServletContextHandler doesn't allow to override the handle method.

Comment: `ServletContextHandler` has it's own access controls built-in, and you can easily extend from `DefaultServlet.service()` to accomplish the same end goal.