# Directory listing with embedded Jetty and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jetty

I try to enable directory listing in Spring Boot v2.7.0 with embedded Jetty by implementing a WebServerFactoryCustomizer:

```
public class MyJettyWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(JettyServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer = new JettyServerCustomizer() {
            
            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
                Handler[] childHandlersByClass = server.getChildHandlersByClass(WebAppContext.class);
                final WebAppContext webAppContext = (WebAppContext) childHandlersByClass[0];
                ServletHandler handler = webAppContext.getServletHandler();
                
                ServletHolder defServlet = ((WebAppContext)server.getHandlers()[0]).getServletHandler().getServlets()[0];
                defServlet.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
                defServlet.setInitParameter("resourceBase","/tmp/");
                webAppContext.getServletHandler().addServletWithMapping(defServlet, "/foo");
                webAppContext.getServletHandler().getServletMapping("/foo").setDefault(true);        
            }
            
        };  
        factory.addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer);
    }
}
```

But requesting `http://localhost:8080/foo` returns a 404. Creating a new Default Servlet does also not work:

```
                ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder();
                holder.setName("default");
                holder.setClassName("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet");
                holder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
                holder.setInitOrder(1);
                webAppContext.getServletHandler().addServletWithMapping(holder, "/foo");
                webAppContext.getServletHandler().getServletMapping("/foo").setDefault(true);
```

Did I fundamentally misunderstand something or did I miss something else like another configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ...

```java
webAppContext.getServletHandler().addServletWithMapping(defServlet, "/foo");
webAppContext.getServletHandler().getServletMapping("/foo").setDefault(true);
```

That has 2 problems.

1. The ServletHandler is an internal class, and is not meant to be manipulated like that, especially after the WebAppContext has been started.

   Use the `WebAppContext` directly if you can (I don't know what state of initialization that particular `WebAppContext` is in).
2. The mapping for `DefaultServlet` *MUST* be a url-pattern with a prefix-match type mapping.

The replacement for those 2 lines would be ...

```java
webAppContext.addServlet(defServlet, "/foo/*");
```

**But wait! there's more!**

You cannot re-use the existing `DefaultServlet` like that (changing the configuration, such as `resourceBase` would break the servlet spec standard `DefaultServlet` behavior in a bad way)

Create a new one, map it to `/foo/*` (be careful of the `pathInfoOnly` init param, as it might prove useful to your setup)

- See [Serving static files from alternate path in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/serving-static-files-from-alternate-path-in-embedded-jetty)