# Embedded Jetty WebSocket server in a different context

Tags: websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-11

I'm trying to run an embedded Jetty websocket server with different content in different contexts.

The websocket part works if I put it in the / context, but I want to server other content there.  The websocket part doesn't work if I put it into any other context.

Here is my code:

```java
    public WebsocketServer(int port, Model model, SessionManager sessionManager) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(port);
        server.setRequestLog((request, response) -> log_.info("request {}", request));

        ContextHandlerCollection handlers = new ContextHandlerCollection();

        ServletContextHandler sch;

        sch = new ServletContextHandler();
        sch.setContextPath("/model");
        sch.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ModelServlet(model)), "/");
        sch.setResourceBase("cfg");
        handlers.addHandler(sch);

        sch = new ServletContextHandler();
        sch.setContextPath("/web");
        sch.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");
        sch.setResourceBase("cfg");
        sch.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"websocket.html"});
        handlers.addHandler(sch);

        sch = new ServletContextHandler();
        sch.setContextPath("/");     // <---- would like to change this context to /ws
        Servlet websocketServlet = new JettyWebSocketServlet() {
            @Override
            protected void configure(JettyWebSocketServletFactory factory) {
                factory.addMapping("/", (req, res) -> {
                    Session s = new Session(req);
                    sessionManager.add(s);
                    return s;
                });
            }
        };
        sch.addServlet(new ServletHolder(websocketServlet), "/");
        JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(sch, null);
        handlers.addHandler(sch);

        sch = new ServletContextHandler();
        sch.setContextPath("/*");
        sch.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");
        sch.setResourceBase("cfg");
        handlers.addHandler(sch);

        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.start();
    }
```

If I put my JettyWebSocketServlet in the / context, it works, but then it never gets to my DefaultServlet.  I have tried changing my JettyWebSocketServlet to /ws, but then my webpage can't connect, but I do get the result from my DefaultServlet.  My ModelServlet works in the /model context in either case.

My webpage tries to connect to ws://localhost:8080/ws

I am using jetty 11.0.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty 11 is now at End of Community Support

See: https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/10485

You have a few fundamental mistakes in your setup.

Your setup also gains nothing by splitting it up into different ServletContexts.

First, your use of `DefaultServlet`, the `DefaultServlet` is always named "default" and on the "default" servlet mapping of `/`.

```java
ServletHolder holderPwd = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
holderPwd.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
scch.addServlet(holderPwd, "/"); // <-- there should always be at least one at "/"
```

If you have a need for more than one `DefaultServlet` then read the past answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20223103/775715

See also the up to date jetty-examples on this subject.

- for Jetty 12 with ee10 environment -> https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/ee10-file-server
- for Jetty 12 core (no servlet) -> https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/file-server

Next, a `ServletContextHandler` cannot have a context-path with a glob symbol.

This is bad, and will not be used unless you somehow send a "*" in the URI path itself.

```java
sch = new ServletContextHandler();
sch.setContextPath("/*"); // <-- this will only map if URI path is exactly `/*`
```

Lastly, if you want websocket to be on `/`, then don't use the `WebSocketServlet` as that will override the `DefaultServlet` behaviors which is not what you want.

Use the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` instead, as this will not interfere with other requests to `/` or `/*` that are not websocket requests.

```java
// Add the websocket filter
JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(sch, (context, configurator) ->
{
    configurator.setIdleTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
    configurator.addMapping("/", (req, res) -> {
        Session s = new Session(req);
        sessionManager.add(s);
        return s;
    });
});
```

See the examples at

- https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/ee10-websocket-jetty-api
- https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/ee10-websocket-jakarta-api

Lastly, your setup is overly complicated.

You can accomplish everything you want to do, with just 1 `ServletContextHandler` and a mix of url-patterns.

```java
// This is Jetty 12 code, against the ee10 environment.

ServletContextHandler sch = new ServletContextHandler();
sch.setContextPath("/");
Resource baseResource = ResourceFactory.of(sch).newClassLoaderResource("cfg");
if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(baseResource))
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find base resource");
sch.setBaseResourceBase(baseResource);

sch.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"websocket.html"});
sch.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ModelServlet(model)), "/model/*");

Resource webResource = ResourceFactory.of(sch).newClassLoaderResource("web");
if (!Resources.isReadableDirectory(webResource))
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find web resource");

ServletHolder holderWeb = new ServletHolder("static-web", DefaultServlet.class);
holderWeb.setInitParameter("baseResource", webResource.getURI().toASCIIString());
holderWeb.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
holderWeb.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
sch.addServlet(holderWeb, "/web/*");

JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(sch, (context, configurator) ->
{
    configurator.setIdleTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
    configurator.addMapping("/ws", (req, res) -> {
        Session s = new Session(req);
        sessionManager.add(s);
        return s;
    });
});

server.setHandler(sch);
```

Comment: Thanks you for such a complete answer.  Some of my mistakes were just me tinkering trying to get things to work.  I was using jetty 11 because we already use it elsewhere, and I couldn't find jetty-servlet v12; I've subsequently found your blog post about that very topic :)

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is Joakim's blog post about the new jetty 12 artifact naming approach: https://webtide.com/new-jetty-12-maven-coordinates/